Diagonal gradient with Imagick PHP
I'm using Imagick in a Symfony Project.
I want to create a logo with 3 layers.
I want for the background, a diagonal gradient with 3 colors.
I've done this for the gradient layer:
$backgroundLayer = new Imagick();
$backgroundLayer->setResolution($logoSize, $logoSize);
$backgroundLayer->newPseudoImage($logoSize, $logoSize, "gradient:$color1-$color2");
$backgroundLayer->setImageFormat("jpg");

Output
Expected
But this gradient is vertical, any idea how to make it 45deg inclined ?
Furthermore, if anyone know how to put 3 colors in a gradient with Imagick, I don't know how to do it.
Thanks in advance

Just do it verically and rotate afterwards. Copy can copy that over if needed.

Thanks for your answer.
I tried to add this line :
$backgroundLayer->rotateImage(new ImagickPixel("none"), 45);
But the gradient don't fill my image :(

Try to recreate this in an image editor. Then you will see the canvas needs to be larger.
